# How we can speed up Joomla webpage

Tags: caching, joomla, system, joomla-extensions

Using Joomla System - Page Cache, my webpage is now around 4-5 sec.

But i have few pages which will be shown only to registered users. I just checked its taking around 10-15 sec. When i inspected using chrome, i can see few things, i have livechat, which is taking around 2 sec, and few things. But live chat is showing in homepage also. but that page is speed.

Wanted to know is Joomla system cache plugin will not work for registered users visible page. or any other plugin i can use to speed up this type of pages.

Comment: You're right, Joomla is slower for logged in users (see: http://www.itoctopus.com/why-is-a-joomla-website-much-slower-for-logged-in-users ). The reason for this is that there are some complex queries that are run only for logged in users, thus slowing the whole thing down. Try optimizing the assets table and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you post the Network - listing in Chrome on the site, to give some more info on what takes time? This will help narrow the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla have one JCH Optimize plugin which will decrease your website load speed.
It will compress all css and js file into one file.That file will store in cache so website speed will be up.

This plugin will be helpful to you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Joomla.
for some components only had the problem of page cache. if u need to clear cache.

and you need to speed up the joomla site 
follow the basic step:

1. Enable Gzip Compression
   Using the Gzip Compression feature, you can compress your website pages before sending them to the user. After that, they will be uncompressed by the user’s browser. And this process takes less time than transferring uncompressed pages.
2. Enable Cache System
3. Optimization Settings (Images, CSS, Java Scripts…)
4. Now Check Your Joomla Website Speed

it may use full to speed up your site.

Comment: thanks, i have tried and activated, but still the page is which is visible for registered users is only slow.

Answer (score 0):

> Wanted to know is Joomla system cache plugin will not work for registered users visible page.

Per the [Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Cache), **Page Caching**:

> Only caches pages for guest visitors (not for logged in visitors)

---

> or any other plugin i can use to speed up this type of pages.

Aside from [JCH Optimize](https://www.jch-optimize.net/) (which was already mentioned), another component I recommend is [JotCache](http://www.jotcomponents.net/home/web-programming/jotcache), which is far better than just the Joomla! default cache.

You may, also, use [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) to analyze your site against both [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) and [Yahoo! Yslow](http://yslow.org/).

Finally, you may try using a CDN to speed up resource delivery. Here are a few:

- [MaxCDN](http://maxcdn.com/)
- [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront)
- [Azure CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/)
- [CDN77](http://www.cdn77.com/)
- [CDNetworks](http://www.us.cdnetworks.com/)
- [CDNlion](http://cdnlion.com/)
- [CacheFly](http://www.cachefly.com/)
- [EdgeCast Networks](http://www.edgecast.com/)
- [KeyCDN](https://www.keycdn.com/?a=3272)
- [SkyparkCDN](https://www.skyparkcdn.ru/)

You can use [CDN for Joomla!](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/cdnforjoomla) to incorporate the CDN technology.

Overall, your best bet is going to be a combination of the CDN and JCH settings to trim down the overall weight of the site using GTmetrix to compare the site after each change.

---

Further reading: [Joomla Performance & Speed](https://joomlaseo.com/performance/)